# Having trouble with adding integers with Python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface

I've been learning Python for the past 4 months now and I'm currentl learning about GUI applications. I'm having trouble trying to add integers after their selected with a CheckBox. The integers do add up but I'm getting these crazy results.

Here's my code:

```
def Calculate(self):
        self.message = "Your total charge = $"

        chargeTotal = 0

        if self.checkBoxVar1.get() == 1:
            chargeTotal += 30
            self.message +=  str(chargeTotal)

        if self.checkBoxVar2.get() == 1:
            chargeTotal += 20
            self.message += str(chargeTotal)

        if self.checkBoxVar3.get() == 1:
            chargeTotal +=  40
            self.message += str(chargeTotal)

        if self.checkBoxVar4.get() == 1:
            chargeTotal +=  100
            self.message += str(chargeTotal)

        if self.checkBoxVar5.get() == 1:
            chargeTotal +=  35
            self.message += str(chargeTotal)

        if self.checkBoxVar6.get() == 1:
            chargeTotal +=  200
            self.message += str(chargeTotal)

        if self.checkBoxVar7.get() == 1:
            chargeTotal += 20
            self.message += str(chargeTotal)

        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Total Charges", self.message)
```

And this is the crazy result I keep getting:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/khpAF.jpg

I know it has to be a simple solution but I'm still very new to Python and can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `self.message += str(chargeTotal)` in each `if` statement and then put it as in code below. Hope it helps.

```
def Calculate(self):
    self.message = "Your total charge = $"

    chargeTotal = 0

    if self.checkBoxVar1.get() == 1:
        chargeTotal += 30

    if self.checkBoxVar2.get() == 1:
        chargeTotal += 20

    if self.checkBoxVar3.get() == 1:
        chargeTotal +=  40

    if self.checkBoxVar4.get() == 1:
        chargeTotal +=  100

    if self.checkBoxVar5.get() == 1:
        chargeTotal +=  35

    if self.checkBoxVar6.get() == 1:
        chargeTotal +=  200

    if self.checkBoxVar7.get() == 1:
        chargeTotal += 20

    self.message += str(chargeTotal)
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Total Charges", self.message)
```

Comment: Wow. I knew I was close. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what you're doing is concatenating numbers converted to strings, at each if statement to your self.message.

eg. if you enter the first two if statements, you first get "Your total charge = $30", and after that, "Your total charge = $3020"

Rather, you should add the chargeTotal to your self.message at the end, only once:

```
def Calculate(self):
    self.message = "Your total charge = $"

    chargeTotal = 0

    if self.checkBoxVar1.get() == 1:
        chargeTotal += 30

    if self.checkBoxVar2.get() == 1:
        chargeTotal += 20

    if self.checkBoxVar3.get() == 1:
        chargeTotal += 40

    if self.checkBoxVar4.get() == 1:
        chargeTotal += 100

    if self.checkBoxVar5.get() == 1:
        chargeTotal += 35

    if self.checkBoxVar6.get() == 1:
        chargeTotal += 200

    if self.checkBoxVar7.get() == 1:
        chargeTotal += 20

    self.message += str(chargeTotal)
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Total Charges", self.message)
```

Comment: Yea, I figured I was doing something like that, now that I look back at the code. Thanks. Imposter Syndrome sucks.